# What is the max amount of simultaneous connections Memgraph supports?

Tags: memgraphdb

What is the max amount of simultaneous connections Memgraph supports? Is there any relation to Bolt workers. I know that [Neo4j has limit on connections/sessions](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/api.html#max-connection-pool-size-ref). Does something like that also exist in Memgraph? Also how does it relay to number of CPUs for `--bolt-num-worker`s?